# How to formalise this English sentence in a conditional statement

Tags: propositional-calculus

1. Let $p$ be the proposition “I will practice more in Discrete Structure Course” and $q$ be the proposition “I will get an A+ in this course”. Express each of these as a combination of $p$ and $q$.

   > To get an A+ in this course, it is necessary for me to practice more in Discrete Structure Course.

My answer is $q\to p$ as $p$ is necessary for $q$. my instructor says it's wrong, what's the correct answer?

Comment: Please leave a comment for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and your professor is incorrect. Yes, when $p$ is necessary for $q$, it becomes $q \rightarrow p$.

Looking at this problem more informally: it may be necessary to practice more in order to get an A+, but of course that does not mean that everyone who practices more *will* get an A+ .. they also need to remain alive for the remainder of the course, for one thing ...